# Will the quantum dot be charged after Auger recombination

Tags: quantum-mechanics

[image: Auger recombination progress]

As the picture shows: an electron−hole pair recombines nonradiatively, transferring the recombination energy to an extra electron, and the extra electron is ejected into the continuum.

My question is: Will the quantum dot be charged after this Auger recombination?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No the quantum dot will not be charged. The electron will be in a continuum state, i.e. it will not "leave" the quantum dot but be a free electron.

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean that the energy of electron is larger than the confinement potential, while it still in the quantum dot? And why?

Comment: This is at odds with the atomic case, where Auger processes will increase the ionic charge (even if the electron hangs around for a while before spatially departing). Are you implying that the electron in the continuum state *cannot* leave the region of the quantum well? If that's not what you mean, at the very least this answer requires some rather more careful handling of language.

Comment: I would say it most certainly _could_ become charged, but it is not required. (More concretely, what is the energy of the Auger electron, what is the mean free path in the quantum dot, and where is it generated all impact whether the electron will escape).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  Yeah, that's what I meant i.e.  I wanted to know  if the electron in the continuum state cannot leave the region of the quantum well/dot, and the corresponding reason.

Comment: @Liang If the electron cannot leave the region of the quantum well, I would find the use of both the teens 'continuum' and 'Auger' to be misleading, but maybe solid-state people have their reasons.